# C++11: Random Numbers using C++11 Random Number Support Library, Generate Same Sequence Each Run

Tags: c++, c++11, random

## Question

Is it possible to seed the `mt19937_64` engine in such a way that the same sequence is generated each time a program is run?

I presume this is possible, as there is a seed function. However I don't know if this will do what I want it to, or will work as I expect, generating the same sequence each time.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Probably from people that didn't want to read through the wall of text. Your entire post can be reduced to this sentence - *Is it possible to seed the `mt19937_64` engine in such a way that the same sequence is generated each time a program is run?*. The answer is yes, construct it by seeding it with the same value each time.

Comment: @user3728501: this is a very poorly written question. SO is about questions and answers, its not a forum, you should not post all the details of your job or even your project. Almost every "chapter" of your question is entirely irrelevant, only the TLDR part belongs on SO. If you write questions that people can't easily understand, then they can't easily be searched later by people needing help either. Which makes them bad questions for the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the seed using `seed` or call the constructor that takes a seed. In either case ensure you are passing some constant such as `27423`.